# Is it possible to have lowercase globals?

Tags: templating

My question is simple and straightforward. Maybe I am making a mistake but it seems that all the text in a global field is always capital. I want to have 'Eng" in a global plain text field but it outputs "ENG"

Answer (score 5):

If you have a global set named *globalSet*, and a plain text field in that set named *textField*, and the value you enter is *Eng*, then `{{globalSet.textField}}` will output *Eng*

Things that could be going wrong:

- caps-lock: Did you enter *ENG* in the field in the first place?
- *|upper*: `{{globalSet.textField|upper}}` will output *ENG*
- CSS: `text-transform: uppercase;`
- jQuery: `$("*").text($("*").text().toUpperCase());` (or other jQuery)
- all caps font
- translations: `{{globalSet.textField|t}}` and a translation file with `"Eng" => "ENG"`

[edited to fold in suggestions from the coments - Marion]

Comment: Another thing that could be going wrong, CSS. ;) Double check for `text-transform: uppercase`.

Comment: Yeah, and also double check for jQuery `$("*").text($("*").text().toUpperCase());`

Comment: One more: you could be using an "All caps font"?!

Comment: What could also cause this is translations. `{{globalSet.textField|t}}` and a translation file with `"Eng" => "ENG"`!

Comment: Go into your global and copy it to the clipboard, then open up Microsoft word and paste it in the contents of your global field into a new document. Highlight the text you want to be lowercase and select the 'Aa' button and select "Capitalize each word". The text is now changed into the format your template requires. Place this text back into your global and click save. 

I have taken the time to ensure my instructions are clear by taking a screenshot of the Microsoft Word menu item: http://glui.me/?i=gsxz5xohmgyq8av/2014-07-03_at_3.15_pm.png/

Please let me know if you need further assistance

Comment: @Luke this is a very nice tutorial, good work, but why didn't you make it a dedicated answer?!

Comment: @ChristianSeelbach i'm working on a more detailed answer and hope to release a beta in a few weeks.

Comment: @Moin please keep in mind, that if you are following Luke's tutorial you still could encounter problems with error options 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6!